# Netbeans Java code formatting issues

Tags: java, netbeans

I'd like to have some pieces of Java code formatted in more compact way than default Netbeans formatting behaviour, however, I wasn't able to set Netbeans formatting options for code snippets bellow properly, so I'll try to ask here:

**1/** Is is possible to set Netbeans formatting to leave single line method as is? For example:

```
public void printMessage(String message) { System.out.println(message); }
```

default behaviour formats this snippet as below:

```
public void printMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

**2/** Is it possible to have double braces initialization in this form?

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    // some code here
}};
```

Netbeans always breaks this code into

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
    {
        // some code here
    }
};
```

Thanks for tips.

Comment: I filed [an enhancement request](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=235024) a while ago but it doesn't look like they did anything about it.

Comment: @assylias thanks, I voted for the enhancement request, hope somebody from NB guys will notice

Comment: ok I have found the issue with double braces initialization reported in Netbeans bugzilla (https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=153677), however, this report is from 2008 and without any progress

Comment: Yes it doesn't look like they are very reactive on the formatting enhancement requests...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these sites for more info.

-https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-formatting-screencast.html

-http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=519945&seqNum=15

To adjust formatting rules for Java files:

- Choose Tools -> Options.
- Click Editor in the left panel and select the Indentation tab.
- Adjust the properties for the indentation engine to your taste.
- Reformat each file to the new rules by opening the file and pressing Ctrl + Shift + F (with no text selected).

Comment: Your links are just general information about formatting and don't answer the question.

Comment: @assylias, Yes, My bad. Better?

Comment: Not really - you explain how to auto format in Netbeans, which the OP seems to know already. But you don't answer his specific question on how to keep a one line method on one line.

Comment: @Johan thanks, but in these Options > Editor > Formatting settings, I was not able to set the behaviour just to fit my requirements, this is the reason why I posted the question here on SF hoping in advice from someone experienced :-)